# UiPath Studio version control: Git vs. TFS

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops, uipath, uipath-studio

I'm currently working on the Topic UiPath - Version Control. I saw that I can connect the studio via Git, TFS and SVN. From my understanding, TFS is nothing else than Azure DevOps and Azure DevOps is using Git as technology. So now my question: Is there a difference between using the Git and the TFS functionality in UiPath Studio when connecting with Azure DevOps?

Cheers and thanks!

Comment: Yes, there is a difference: Git and TFVC are different version control technologies. Do research and understand the difference between Git and TFVC, then choose one.

Comment: Hi there. Yes, I know that Git and TFVC are different technologies. But the question was not related to TFVC, it was related to TFS, what is Azure DevOps. Thatswhy the question.

Comment: TFS is a platform that can host Git repositories and TFVC repositories. If you want to use TFVC, use the TFVC connector. If you want to use Git, use the Git connector. TFS can host both.

Comment: I understand that TFS can host Git and TFVC, my question is more related to UiPath Studio, where i can choose between Git and TFS. I mean I could also connect to TFS via Git, why should i choose TFS then?

Comment: Because Git and TFVC are different version control systems. You choose "TFS" if you want to use TFVC. You choose Git if you want to use Git, regardless of where the Git repo is hosted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From my understanding, TFS is nothing else than Azure DevOps and Azure
>   DevOps is using Git as technology.

You may have some misunderstanding about TFS.

TFS the full name is Team Foundation Server name changed name to Azure DevOps Server, is the on-premises version of Azure DevOps Service. It has both Git and TFVC as source control, not only for Git.

However there is a little difference for this(TFS) in UiPath Studio. It offers the tools to connect automation projects to version control systems through the Team page in the Backstage view.

It provides three types:**Git , TFS ,SVN**.

[image]

After go through [official link](https://docs.uipath.com/studio/v2019-fastTrack/docs/tfs-version-control) in UiPath Studio.  TFS Version in UiStudio should just be TFVC version control.

The folder path, and description of "check out" all indicate it's actually TFVC version control in TFS. I haven't used and verified in UiPath Studio. Below conclusion is surmised according to official tutorial in UiPath Studio.

So the difference should be:

- If you want to use **TFVC** in TFS, you need to use TFS Version Control
  to connect TFS url.
- If you want to use **Git** in TFS, you need to use Git Version Control to
  connect Git repo url.
- If you want to use **Git** provided by others such as GitHub, you need to
  use Git Version Control to connect GitHub repo url.

Hope this is clearly.

Comment: Hi,
Many thanks, now it's clear for me :) Allthough i think that UiPath should name it TFVC instead of TFS because its a little bit confusing. Nevertheless, that means for me that I will use the Git option also for Azure DevOps.

Answer (score 0):

I think the difference between both is clear. You need to decide what features you need.

You also asked where to find the Settings page of Git and TFS. You can find it under **Home** and **Team**:

[image: Team settings]